# How to catch error that iPad make phone call get error "iPhone calls not available"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, phone-call, openurl

I have a question about phone call using iPad.
I try to make phone call, but I got error in iPad by system.
How can I control this error message like following image?
How to catch this error?
thanks.

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneText];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",value]] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

[image: error messagee]

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the function `openURL:options:completionHandler:` you can use the function `canOpenURL:`. You can find the [reference here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl?language=objc).

In your case the function will return false and you can provide a fallback.

```c
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneText];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",value]];

if (url && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
} else {
    // your fallback - you can display an alert controller
}
```